# I want to print a breakout board for CH201 sensor on EAGLE

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, proximity-sensor, breakout

I am completely new to the world of printed circuit board design.

I want to connect this [CH201 ultrasonic sensor](https://invensense.tdk.com/download-pdf/ch201-datasheet/) to a breadboard, but the sensor is extremey small and the pins are the width of wires. I need to make a breakout board on EAGLE so it becomes slightly easier to solder it and use it on the breadboard. The problem is I don't know how to even get started on creating the EAGLE design.

What components I need?

I have created a model for the CH201 sensor, but what kind of holes do I need on the PCB? Do I need thru holes on the sides which extends inwards to connect to the CH201 pins (something like [this?](https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/lga-to-dip-smt-adapters/60905))

Just a general overview of what I should be doing would be extremely helpful as I can research on my own once I get the basic understanding.

Comment: Find some YouTube tutorials.

Comment: Yeah, lets go watch videos of people who don't know what they are doing mumbling their way through a poorly defined task that may not even be the task at hand - but you can't tell until you've watched half of an hour long fuzzy video.

Comment: *but what kind of holes do I need on the PCB?* Those that match the connectors you want to use. There are 2.54mm pitch pinheaders in the the standard eagle libraries. You may want to use those. I recommend not to use SMT pin headers for breadboard purposes, they become loose easily.

Comment: I don't know about Eagle, but there are some good Kicad videos on YouTube. I learned Kicad by watching videos, I had never used any PCB software previously. I had *watched* other people use various other PCB software during my career as the implemented my designs on PCBs, so I knew the process and terminology.